# Which SATA port is my disk connected to?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, command-line, boot, sata

We have a computer with multiple boot drives, all of which contain the same software.  The selection of the boot disk is via multi-position switch on the front panel.  If disk 1 is selected, the disk on SATA Port 0 is booted.  If disk 2 is selected, the disk on SATA Port 1 is booted.  Etc.

The disk manager on RH can show which SATA port the hard disks are plugged in.  It's a graphical UI on top of *something*, and that *something* is what I want.

How can I get this information on the command line?  I connect via an ssh connection and I'd like to find out what the boot disk is connected to.  Where is this information kept?

Thanks!

Comment: You do realize the RH disk manager is open source, right?

Comment: AFAIK, disk-manager only shows the device paths of every installed drive, like `/dev/(sda|sdb)`, which don't necessarily correspond to the physical ports the drives are attached to.

Comment: @geewee http://www.orbdesigns.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/GnomeDiskUtility.png It's the third option down in the left column of the right pane.

Comment: lshw should give you the information you need.

Comment: you can get some hints from `ls -l /dev/disk/by-path/`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Matching up port numbers to devices

I found this question because I was trying to figure out the same thing. Here's what I figured out; it should work in bash or zsh:

```
for i in /dev/disk/by-path/*;do [[ ! "$i" =~ '-part[0-9]+$' ]] && echo "Port $(basename "$i"|grep -Po '(?<=ata-)[0-9]+'): $(readlink -f "$i")";done
```

The output should look something like this:

```
Port 1: /dev/sda
Port 2: /dev/sdb
Port 3: /dev/sdc
```

These port numbers **SHOULD** correspond with the numbers printed on your motherboard, although this assumes your motherboard vendor was considerate enough to match the numbers printed on the board to the port numbers in the SATA controller chip. At very least, device paths remain stable, so once you establish a mapping between the listed port numbers and the numbers on the panel, it won't ever change.

This snippet iterates over the `/dev/disk/by-path` directory. It skips over files that end in `-part<number>` as these are just partitions, and extracts the port number from the `-ata<number>` at the end of the remaining filenames. These files are symlinks to the traditional `/dev/sdX` nodes, which it gets using `readlink -f`.

If you have multiple SATA controllers, you'll get multiple devices listed for the same port numbers, because each controller has its own port 1, port 2, etc. So, just run `ls -l /dev/disk/by-path` and parse it out manually.

## Figuring out which device is your boot device

To figure out which one is your boot device, run `mount | grep ' on / ' | cut -f 1 -d ' '`. This shows the device mounted at `/`.

Answer (score 0):

The proper SATA port mapping is what "user371366" have mentioned.

Although I highly advice to not rely on what SATA port number is printed on the motherboard PCB.

Because there are hardware/software issues or bugs which makes them unreliable.

There will be times when SATA port#1 labeled on motherboard PCB, will be shown as SDB or SDx (where x is any letter shown on your PC terminal or whatnot) and not SDA.

This happened to me few times such as using the "clonezilla" backup software, where it shows SATA port#1 as SDB when it should be SDA.

The best approach is to write down the hard drive serial number and use that as reference of which hard drive is being targeted.